# A huge difference in reserved memory between two requests

Tags: sql

This request takes about 30 megabytes of memory from the database where 4.5k of suitable fields are located

```
string(60) "SELECT qr FROM App\Entity\User qr WHERE u.email LIKE :domain"
```

But this request goes beyond 8 gigabytes of memory

```
string(78) "SELECT u FROM App\Entity\User qr, App\Entity\User u WHERE u.email LIKE :domain"
```

The problem appeared during the work on the query for the database, which will process all users with a certain email, I found the problem that the doctrine did not make the queries that I wanted and the problem was solved. However, I am wondering why there is such a huge difference in the resources consumed between these two requests.

Is there a logical answer to this?

PS: the number of fields in the database is 4.5 thousand and each field is suitable for the query conditions, therefore both queries return the same number of users on a small number of fields in the database (for example 100), however when I increased the number to 4.5 thousand actually, and such a question arose

Comment: The second query performs a ```CROSS JOIN``` of ```App\Entity\User``` (respectively the table ```user```) with itself. This will give you ```(#rows)^2``` rows which is much more than only the 4.5k you have in the table. The second query should also give you each row of the first query but 4.5k times (since every single result is matched with all users). For further analysis, the underlying DBMS would be nice to know.

Comment: This might be better asked in the sister site DBA.StackExchange.com

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by adding the same table twice with two different aliases, and no join condition between them? As @Islingre says the way you have it is a cross product join.

Comment: Islingre gives good answer , i think question can be clossed, thank you for your answers , and Islingre thank you more))